# activate and deactivate nav-link bootstrap in html jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 2 links , one is for upload a report and the other to preview.. at first the second one is disabled because i put it in the class but then when i upload the report i want to enable this link with jquery in the event, Im trying to do something like this but i can´t

```
$("#linkPreview").prop( "disabled", false );
```

.html

```
     <li class="nav-title"> Report</li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/#upload">
                <i class="nav-icon icon-notebook"></i>
                Upload Report
              </a>
              <a class="nav-link disabled" id="linkPreview" href="/#preview">
                <i class="nav-icon icon-notebook"></i>
                Preview Report
              </a>
            </li>
```

Maybe is better to disable with jquery at document.ready function and enable in the event but also i don´t find the way to do..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally using the function removeClass it works!

```
$("#linkPreview").removeClass("disabled");
```